# What is the time complexity of sending an array inside navigate hook in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, navigation, time-complexity

I have 2 ways to solve my problem. I have to send an array to another page, or I will send the endpoint of gives this array and will fetch the array again. How can i learn time complexity of sending an array inside navigate hook (in state field) with react-router-dom while navigating page ?
Which one would be faster in this problem ?

Comment: I think that time complexity is irrelevant in this case.  Time complexity is used to measure how different algorithms change they time for input data size.

Answer (score 0):

The data that is passed in route state is serialized, so the "time complexity"  of serializing an array to pass in the state is *at least* `O(n)`. It's basically "JSON.stringify" or `Array.prototype.toString`. This is all in memory so it'll be *relatively* quick as compared to refetching anything over a network connection.

"Which is faster/better/etc" type questions tend to be fairly subjective and often closed as being opinionated, but in this case it should be fairly obvious that passing some data you've already fetched would be faster than refetching it again.